# Compare two outputs from dpkg --get-selections > output.txt

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have two installed package lists in .txt files

This command was run on two different machines with same distro of Linux

```
dpkg --get-selections > output.txt
```

I need to get packages that are installed on first one (production)
But not installed on second one (clean install machine), and install the packages that are not installed.

Comment: [Compute a list of difference between packages installed on two hosts](http://serverfault.com/questions/328642/compute-a-list-of-difference-between-packages-installed-on-two-hosts)

Comment: Thank you for this one, I have read it before, id dod not suit me well for my purpose. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the changes between system A and system B do:

```
$ diff -u systemA.txt systemtB.txt
```

This will result in output like:

```
--- a   2014-06-01 21:44:48.501128132 +0100
+++ b   2014-06-01 21:47:26.450197702 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+aalib                          install
 accountsservice                    install
 acl                        install
 acpi                       install
@@ -5,7 +6,6 @@
 acpi-support                   install
 acpi-support-base              install
 acpid                      install
-adduser                        install
```

Lines prefixed by `+` are packages that were present on system B but not system A.
Lines prefixed by `-` are packages that were present on system A but not system B.

To find all of the packages that were installed on one system but not the other you can extract the install lines that begin with `+`:

```
$ diff -u a b|grep install|grep '^+'
+aalib                          install
```